# PHP5, require_once, failed to open stream

Tags: apache, path, require-once

I have a problem which I can't solve and I have been searching about this problem for days...

This is my /var/log/apache2/error.log file:

```
PHP Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/diagramo/editor/common./license.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/diagramo/editor/common/delegate.php(1) : eval()'d code(54) : eval()'d code on line 5

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/diagramo/editor/common./license.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/diagramo/editor/common/delegate.php(1) : eval()'d code(54) : eval()'d code on line 5
```

I want to run this Diagram-Sketch-Software on my Apache2 server.
The setup site of Diagramo works fine but when I whant to go to the start page I get a blank site...

1. The delegate.php exists but not the required delegate.php(1) file.
2. I enabled the "include_path=..." in php.ini
3. The path: `/var/www/html/diagramo/editor/common./license.php` exists but without the
   dot behind (common.)

please help me I'm kinda new in that

Comment: please show directory path for both files. once again check path.

Comment: Where do i have to edit require_once?

Comment: Thank you. The strange thing is that delegate.php and license.php has nothing in it exept one large string. But i will try it out

Comment: this sketch-program is quite a pain in the ass. I changed it as you said. The error is gone but I got a new one... `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Delegate' not found in /var/www/html/diagramo/editor/common/rememberme.php on line 7`

Comment: in that file I only changed the path of delegate.php. this is line 6 and 7: `require_once('/var/www/html/diagramo/editor/common/delegate.php');
$delegate = new Delegate();` In this file is no Class declared...

Answer (score 0):

Try this because both files are in same directory.

```
require_once(license.php)
```